# Scroll to top of artboard shortcut in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

In Sketch, if you have a really tall artboard and want to quickly scroll to the top of it, is there any shortcut to do so other than mouse scrolls? Because the up/down keys (not the main four arrow keys)  change the page, instead of panning up/down.

The up/down arrow keys with a horizontal line on them seem to me like they should be used to go to the top/bottom of the artboard, but they don't do anything.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to use this plugin.
https://github.com/Arkkimaagi/Bookmark/blob/master/README.md
This allows you to save 5 bookmarks per page and navigate quickly between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that’s impossible.

A really hacky and weird pseudo-solution would be to turn on “Zoom in on selection” under “Canvas” in the app settings, and then chose a layer element in the layer list that is on the top of the artboard and zoom in on it to have Sketch jump to that area. But I’m sure that's not a satisfactory solution, haha.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a plugin just for this:

- Scroll to top of artboard
- Zoom artboard to 75%

Hope it helps!

Download: 
https://github.com/diegoiglesias/zoomTools